# Batch script to add a number next to each prime number

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-line

I want to create a script that does the action:
Enter first number then last number,And what is obtained is that for each number child, numbers from 1 to 3 will appear

---

first number=1

last number=2

What you get is this:

- 1 1
- 1 2
- 1 3
- 2 1
- 2 2
- 2 3

What I managed is this file

```
@echo off
set /p F=first number:
set /p L=last number:

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /L %%A IN (%F%,1,%L%) DO (
set /A result=%%A %% 3
echo %%A !result!
)
```

But the result is not good enough

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need are nested `for` loops:

```
@echo off
set /p F=first number:
set /p L=last number:

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /L %%A IN (%F%,1,%L%) DO (
  for /L %%B in (1,1,3) do (
    echo %%A %%B
  )
)
```